# How to to list array values that are equal or greater to user inputed value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I'm looking to write javascript code that creates an integer array of numbers, prompts the user to input a minimum number (minNumber), and then display the values in the array that are equal to or higher than minNumber input. I was able to do almost all of that in the code below, but it displayed all of the array's values instead of just displaying the values that are equal to or higher than minNumber, as I originally intended. I would like to keep the basic formatting with the function etc, but can you please advise what i can add to my code to achieve the desired result? Thanks so much

```js
function arrayFunction(arrayOne, minNumber) {
  for (var number = 0; number <= arrayOne.length; number++) {
    if (arrayOne[number] >= minNumber) {
      document.write("The array numbers starting from minNumber are " + arrayOne[number] + " ");
      return arrayOne.slice(number, arrayOne.length);
    }
  }
  return;
}


const NEW_LINE = "<br/>";       // This is like one ENTER key-press
const NEW_PARAGRAPH = "<p/>";   // This is like two ENTER key-presses

let arrayOne = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
var minNumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter in the min. number"));
let array = arrayFunction(arrayOne, minNumber);

document.write(array);
```

Comment: You've gotten off to a great start. Have you considered using the [Array Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter your array? You will probably get a bunch of slack here for using `document.write()` as it is generally frowned upon. But your use here is just fine.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks so much! I will check out the array filter method. What would you recommend i replace document.write() with?

Comment: Rather than `document.write()`, it is always preferred to add the values you want to print to an existing element in the DOM.

Comment: Please see my answer for how to use `filter`.

Comment: I have also updated my answer to demonstrate one way to place the content into the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You've essentially written the [Array Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

The problem is with the return statements. You need to return the array after to loop has completed rather than in it.

If you prefer to skip all the code you can simply use `filter()`:

```js
let arrayOne = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
var minNumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter in the min. number"));
let array = arrayOne.filter(item => item >= minNumber);
console.log(array);

document.getElementById('output').textContent = array;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayOne.filter((val) => val >= minNumber);
```

Just put this line in with `return` in the function.